# How can a function finish it's objective, only to break down after returning to main?

Tags: c++

From what I've seen, sometimes in codeblocks a certain code will only work a certain part of the times it's run, how can it be possible, that without compiling such code again, it only works let's say two thirds of the times.
Shouldn't codes always work or not work?
Note that these codes don't depend on time and keep getting (0xC0000005) pointers error.

On the other hand, I have a code that does just the same.

I've tried making the function that I suspect doesn't work, print something that confirms it indeed finishes the function. I also suspect it's because it is a void function alterating a certain object.

```
graph G (0);
cout<<"Starting construction"<<endl;
G.Construct();
cout<<"Printing"<<endl;
cout<<G;
```

When it works, it prints the graph:

```
Starting construction
Ending construction
Printing
1 : (1, 2, 1)(1, 4, 1)

2 : (2, 1, 1)

3 : (3, 2, 1)

4 : (4, 2, 1)(4, 3, 1)
```

When it doesn't, it prints :

```
Starting construction
Ending construction
```

Comment: Sounds like you have undefined behavior in your code.  That means anything can happen.

Comment: Telltale signs of undefined behavior.

Comment: Please provide [mcve].

Comment: Undefined behaviour can explain that. As can threads without proper synchronization (but then, that's just UB again). In short: a broken/incorrect program may do *anything*. Once you stray outside the bounds of behaviour guaranteed by the standard; all bets are off.

Comment: My question is more oriented about why does it sometimes work, and sometimes doesn't, no code changes, no rebuilds, nothing. Just random.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Not looking for verification, looking for the why can it sometimes work.

Comment: @MarioAldean In that case, it was already explained to you: undefined behavior somewhere in your code.

Comment: @NathanOliver that was indeed the issue, I corrected my previously overlooked error with such new information and now my code works, thank you!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I had:

```
    for (int i=0; i<6;i++)
    {
        S[i].resize(n);
    }
```

where `S` is a `std::vector`.

I replaced `6` (the loop extent) with `m` (even though m = 6).

This seems to have solved the issue. Undefined behaviour at its best.

Comment: This isn't a very good answer. This may have solved or hid at least one problem with the code, but there is no way for anyone else to connect the dots from the question to this answer due to the lack of code in the question.

Comment: @user4581301 I just showed how something that looks unrelated (since stl libraries often behave well) can cause such errors. I'm sorry but connecting the points would mean to not take anything for granted as a simple m=6. I didn't even know what undefined behaviour was. Also, I made different examples with 7, 8, 9 so I'm pretty sure it solved the error.